# Why does converting objects to JSON does not required @XmlRootElement

Tags: json, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I'm learning RESTful webservices using Java (Wildfly server), during a video, the tutor said the JAXB converts an object to xml, then converts that xml to JSON.
So in order to have XML document, we need to annotate our class with `@XmlRootElement`, but to get JSON, we can omit the `@XmlRootElement`. 
So if, under the hood, JAXB converts the document to xml in order to get josn, and we can omit `@XmlRootElement` for json, why is it required for XML documents?

Comment: Could you provide the link to the video?

Comment: its a pluralsight video series, called `RESTFul Services in Java using Jersey` under the `04. Using HTTP GET` chapter, a video called `10. JSON Output`, here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/4wH8MWb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of JSON's less structured format. It uses the same parsing engine, but doesn't care if it is well formed vs valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it a bit mixed up I guess, JAXB is not intended to convert XML to JSON. You can use JAXB to marshal/unmarshal to/from XML/JSON to Java objects.